# mongodb: pthread_create failed: errno:11

Tags: mongodb, ulimit

I want to run sharelatex on my vServer (CentOS 6). I installed everything but sharelatex won't start. The mongod.log says after accepting some connections:

```
2015-02-12T12:04:30.971+0100 [initandlisten] pthread_create failed: errno:11 Resource temporarily unavailable
2015-02-12T12:04:30.971+0100 [initandlisten] can't create new thread, closing connection
```

I already increased the ulimits:

```
[root@vServer]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256270
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 21000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256270
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

can anyone help me?

edit:
I also checked the limits of the mongod process:

```
[root@vServer]# cat //proc/552/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            10485760             unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             62848                62848                  processes
Max open files            21000                21000                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       256270               256270               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0      
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

edit2:

Here ist the output of ulimit:

```
[root@vServer]# ulimit -Sa
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256270
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 21000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256270
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

[root@vServer]# ulimit -Ha
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256270
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 21000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256270
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

but as you can see I am logged in as root. Shouldn't show cat //proc/552/limits the actual limits for the process?

Comment: What's the output of `ulimit -Sa` and `ulimit -Ha`? If you're not running as a root user, the system-wide limits could be lower than the limits the non-root user is setting, in which case the lower system settings override.

Comment: I added the output to my original question...

Comment: no ideas? I tried sharelatex on CentOS, openSUSE and Ubuntu and got always the same error...

Answer (score 4):

I've had problems with the `/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count` kernel parameter with mongodb.  Basically mongodb is trying to allocate more than 65k memory maps, which is the stock kernel limit.

When had this problem, the errors were the same ones you posted involving pthread_create failing.  To fix it, I just did the below as root:

```
echo 2048000 > /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

Whether or not this works, I highly recommend using `strace` on the mongodb pid to try to see where it's failing.  I don't think the error message you see is necessarily leading you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply! When I try to change the value I get a 'permission denied' error. I also tried to change it via 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=2048000'. I am logged in as root. Maybe a running process is blocking the file. I will try to stop some processes and try again.